# Can't find my mongo database using Robo3t, which is up and running

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Well my database is connected but it is not showing in Robo3T

```
mongoose
 .connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("DB CONNECTED");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("CORRUPTED DB");
  });
```

Here is the Database URI:

```
DATABASE = "mongodb://localhost:27017/ecomm"
```

> App is running at 3000

> DB CONNECTED

There is no "ecomm" database

```
@(shellhelp2):1:1
> show dbs
admin           0.000GB
config          0.000GB
digitalmanipur  0.015GB
local           0.000GB
tantha_backend  0.000GB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we need to make some changes in the models of the database, then only it will reflect.

> OK! my bad, I haven't updated the database yet